# How to let esbuild ( in browser ) know to search for import files in local storage?

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, babeljs, webassembly, esbuild

> I'm trying to build an online react code editor and I have to transpile code from the Monaco code editor. My files are stored in local storage, for example, ->

```js
import "./styles.css";
import Modal from "./components/Modal";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Modal />
    </div>
  );
}
```

> the component Modal is stored in local storage. while transpiling the
> code how can I let the build know to search for this type of imports
> in localStorage?

Comment: What is Modal component? Do you store the component in local storage?